# Scraping a table appearing on click with python

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, scrape

I want to scrape information from this [page](http://www.etf.com/SHE).

Specifically, I want to scrape the table which appears when you click "View all" under the "TOP 10 HOLDINGS" (you have to scroll down on the page a bit).

I am new to webscraping, and have tried using BeautifulSoup to do this. However, there seems to be an issue because the "onclick" function I need to take into account. In other words: The HTML code I scrape directly from the page doesn't include the table I want to obtain.

I am a bit confused about my next step: should I use something like selenium or can I deal with the issue in an easier/more efficient way?

Thanks.

My current code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


Soup = BeautifulSoup
my_url = 'http://www.etf.com/SHE'
page = requests.get(my_url)
htmltxt = page.text

soup = Soup(htmltxt, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

Comment: api: `'http://www.etf.com/view_all/holdings/SHE'`, but you must have `my_url` as referer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a json response from the api: `http://www.etf.com/view_all/holdings/SHE`. The table you're looking for is located in `'view_all'`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

url = 'http://www.etf.com/SHE'
api = "http://www.etf.com/view_all/holdings/SHE"
headers = {'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest', 'Referer':url}
page = requests.get(api, headers=headers)
htmltxt = page.json()['view_all']
soup = Soup(htmltxt, "html.parser")
data = [[td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')] for tr in soup.find_all('tr')]

print('\n'.join(': '.join(row) for row in data))
```

Comment: Follow-up question: On the same page, I would like to retrieve the data for sectors and countries. Both are in the same format. Can I use a similar API for these? And how can I see whether an API is available?

Comment: @Emjora you'll have to inspect the network traffic (click inspect > network > xhr). So the api for sectors should be `http://www.etf.com/etf-chart/top-10-sectors-json/SHE`, and for countries `http://www.etf.com/etf-chart/top-10-countries-json/SHE`.